# Combine get-ChildItem with ACL powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Im looking for some help on information on files using Power shell, we have got most of when we need apart from the owner information.

the code below returns a list of directories that are older then 1 year, but the problem is we cannot seem to get the Owner Information to show in there:

```
gci -r 
"D:\Network Shares\ICT\ICT\Network Shares\ICT\Innovations\Robert Pitt" | ? 
{
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)} >> D:\temp\ICTFileAge.txt
}
```

We know of the command called `Get-ACL`, but were unsure how to tie it all up.

Anyone have any ideas please, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
gci -r "D:\Network Shares\ICT\ICT\Network Shares\ICT\Innovations\Robert Pitt" |
? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)} |
 % {$_ | add-member -name "Owner" -membertype noteproperty -value (get-acl $_.fullname).owner -passthru} |
  Select fullname,lastwritetime,owner
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, we got it working although the `-passthu` was throwing error's, what was this for, Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "-passthru". Without that, it won't pass the object on down the pipeline after it adds the new member.  I corrected the code in the post.

Comment: We have exported the result set into an CSV Spread sheet which look's ok, can't see any errors etc, but would it be possible that were are missing lines because of that ?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Whether it needs the -passthru or not will depend on how your script was written, but it's going to be a all or nothing deal.  You'll either get them all or you won't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be simplified by using a calculated property to pull in the ACL owner field:

```
$Path = 'c:\'

Get-ChildItem $Path |
Select-Object *,@{name='owner';expression={
(get-acl $_.FullName).owner}}
```